# Display multiple plotly plots in Shiny (only one appears)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to plot two plotly pie charts side by side in the Shiny main panel, but only the last one shows up. However, the two plots could be produced without problem individually.

As an example, my code below.
Starting from the `mtcars` dataset, I created two extra columns listing the manufacturer and random categories (`Sport` and `Sedan`).

```
mtcars$manuf <- unlist(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "))[1]
mtcars$Category <- c(rep("Sport", 22), rep("Sedan", 10))
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb manuf   Cat
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 Mazda Sport
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 Mazda Sport
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 Mazda Sport
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Mazda Sport
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Mazda Sport
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 Mazda Sport
```

From there, the app user can choose between `ligth (mtcars$wt < 3)` and `heavy (mtcars$wt >=3)` cars.

My `app.R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


mtcars$manuf <- unlist(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "))[1]
mtcars$Category <- c(rep("Sport", 22), rep("Sedan", 10))


ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(     
            selectInput(
                inputId = "select",
                label = "Select car weigth:",
                choices = c("All","light","heavy")
            ),                
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotlyOutput("view")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    dataset <- reactive({
        switch(input$select,
            "All" = mtcars,
            "light" = subset(mtcars, wt < 3),
            "heavy" = subset(mtcars, wt >= 3)
        )
    })

    output$view <- renderPlotly({

        # First plot
        df1 <- dataset() %>% group_by(manuf)
        df1 <- df1 %>% summarize(count=n())
        fig1 <- df1 %>% plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count)
        fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_pie(hole = 0.6)
        fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(title = "Manufacturers",showlegend = F)

        # Second plot
        df2 <- dataset() %>% group_by(Category)
        df2 <- df2 %>% summarize(count=n())
        fig2 <- df2 %>% plot_ly(labels = ~Category, values = ~count)
        fig2 <- fig2 %>% add_pie(hole = 0.6)
        fig2 <- fig2 %>% layout(title = "Categories",showlegend = F)

        # Grouped plots
        subplot(fig1, fig2)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Looks like `subplot` won't work for this if you follow the link in the top answer here: https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-plotly-pie-charts-in-one-row/1650

Comment: @Jonny Phelps. Thanks, I did not see that. So it seems we can only have one single formatting, title, etc... for the group of pies.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Include this and give it a try:

```
     fig<-subplot(fig1,fig2)
     fig
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).